# How can I delete all files in a folder, which matches a certain pattern?

Tags: php, file, unlink

I have a folder with images.

As example:

```
z_1.jpg
z_2.jpg
z_3.jpg
//...
```

I want to delete every image with prefix `z_*.jpg`. How can I do that?

```
unlink('z_*.jpg'); ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the exact filename to [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) a file. So just use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all files which you want to grab. Loop through the returned array and delete the files, e.g.

```
<?php

    $files = glob("z_*.jpg");

    foreach($files as $file)
        unlink($file);

?>
```